# Practical implementation of Hindley–Milner with typeclasses — matching vs most general unifier

Tags: type-theory, type-systems, type-inference, haskell

I'm trying to get a deep understanding of a (great) paper ["Typing Haskell in Haskell"](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/). I'm having difficulties understanding the implementation of two methods there — the `mgu` and `match`.

Let's talk about the `TAp` case ([full implementation in the article](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/TypingHaskellInHaskell.html#tth_sEc6)):

```
-- Substitutions are from a type variable to a type
type Subst  = [(Tyvar, Type)]


-- Calculate most general unifier 's' so that:
-- prop> apply s t1 = apply s t2
mgu :: Monad m => Ty.Type -> Ty.Type -> m Subst
mgu (TAp l r) (TAp l' r') = do s1 <- mgu l l'
                               s2 <- mgu (apply s1 r) (apply s1 r')
                               return (s2 @@ s1)              -- <=== THIS
-- ...snip...


-- Matching of t1 and t2 finds a substitution 's' so that:
-- prop> apply s t1 = t2
match :: Monad m => Type -> Type -> m Subst
match (TAp l r) (TAp l' r') = do sl <- match l l'
                                 sr <- match r r'
                                 merge sl sr                  -- <=== THIS
-- ...snip...


-- Substitution composition such that:
-- prop> apply (s1 @@ s2) = apply s1 . apply s2
(@@)       :: Subst -> Subst -> Subst
s1 @@ s2    = [ (u, apply s1 t) | (u,t) <- s2 ] ++ s1


-- A `symmetric' composition of substitutions such that:
-- prop> apply (s1++s2) = apply (s2++s1)
merge :: Monad m => Subst -> Subst -> m Subst
merge s1 s2 = if agree then return (s1 ++ s2) else fail "merge fails"
  where agree = all (\v -> apply s1 (Ty.TVar v) == apply s2 (Ty.TVar v))
                    (map fst s1 `intersect` map fst s2)
```

`match` is [used only for matching predicates](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/TypingHaskellInHaskell.html#tth_sEc7.1), `mgu` is used more often e.g. for [actual type inference](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/TypingHaskellInHaskell.html#tth_sEc10).

I can't wrap my head on why in the `mgu` the substitution composition is sequential and in `match` a *symmetric* composition is used. Why's that?

Furthermore, would it make a difference if I'd change the ordering of unification, so `mgu` would read:

```
mgu (TAp l r) (TAp l' r') = do s1 <- mgu r r'
                               s2 <- mgu (apply s1 l) (apply s1 l')
                               return (s2 @@ s1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I figured it out the next day. It's all dead simple as it came out.

Let's use an example – type applications `z a a` and `z a b` where `z :: * -> * -> *`. The unification will yield that (without further context) `z a a` is the most general type for both giving substitution `{b↦a}`. On the other hand, `z a a` cannot be *matched* to `z a b`, as they are simply different.

So now let's dissect the implementations. The `mgu x@(TAp l r) y@(TAp l' r')` first compares `l` and `l'` giving a substitution `s1 <- mgu l l'`. The `s1` is a *knowledge* of how part of `x` and `y` are different. With that knowledge, we can investigate further; that's why we use `apply` in `s2 <- mgu (apply s1 l) (apply s1 l')` which gives us next premises on how different `x` and `y` are. So the summary is to compose the knowledge: `s2 @@ s1` (ordering is as in function composition, e.g. `g (f (x))` can be written as `(g ∘ f) (x)`).

I believe (without a proof though) that it's possible to just use `s2 <- mgu r r'` and then try to combine `s1` with `s2` though some kind of recursion would be required. Also, I believe it's possible to match `r` with `r'` first and then match `l` with `l'`; the ordering is just to make error messages more obvious (order of reading in a file).

The `match x@(TAp l r) y@(TAp l' r')` is different. We must not approve the first example: `z a a` vs `z a b`. In order to do that we need to:

1. note that `a` from `x` would need to become `a` from `y`
2. note that `a` from `x` would need to become `b` from `y`
3. tell that the above two premises are contradictory

That's the reason to yielding *strange* substitutions like `{a↦a}` which is semantically equivalent to `{}` but allows for taking #1 into account.
The *symmetric* composition takes this additional information. It doesn't put apply in the second sub-matching (`match (apply s1 r) (apply s1 r')`) since applying a substitution would make us lose information about contradictory premises.